# python re - Extract chat text of one person in a large string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to obtain one person's chat text from a large string that has another person also featured in it. The other person's chat text needs to be removed from the string. Usually there's a punctuation mark or a `\n` tag in a simple case, but in this case there's nothing except the other person's name to show the end of a chat. And at times there are multiple chats in a row from one person. An example of a chat text string would be the following (where I'm looking for *only* Joe's chats):

`Joe: hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today Joe: im bored. Mike: hey joe not sure, do you have any plans? Joe: i was thinking about going to the baseball game Joe: I need to get out of the house. Mike: Sounds good I'll meet you there! Mike: Let me know what time you're leaving`

I would eventually need the string to be:

`hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today I'm bored. i was thinking of going to the baseball game I need to get out of the house.`

I'm fine with answers that leave the "Joe" tags in there, I just can't figure out a way to remove the "Mike" tags and chats using `re` in Python. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to remove all strings that match a capital letter, lower case letters, then a colon, with the empty string.

```
import re 
text = re.sub(r'[A-Z][a-z]+:', '', text)
```

The most stable way I would use to remove tags or a certain individual would be to split on the regex

```
text = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]+:)').split(text)[1:]
```

to get a list like:

```
['Joe:', " hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today ", 'Joe:', ' im bored. ', 'Mike:', ' hey joe not sure, do you have any plans? ', 'Joe:', ' i was thinking about going to the baseball game ', 'Joe:', ' Ineed to get out of the house. ', 'Mike:', " Sounds good I'll meet you there! ", 'Mike:', " Let me know what time you're leaving"]
```

You could then iterate over this and make a map for the text of every other element

```
map_ = {}
for i in range(1,len(text),2):
    map_[text[i-1]] = map_.get(text[i-1],'') + text[i]
```

to get a map of the speaker to all their text.

```
{'Joe:': " hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today  im bored.  i was thinking about going to the baseball game  I need to get out of the house. ", 'Mike:': " hey joe not sure, do you have any plans?  Sounds good I'll meet you there!  Let me know what time you're leaving"}
```

then you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Thanks, this removes the tags but I would also need Mike's chats to disappear as well.

Comment: oh, sorry I didn't get that is what you wanted. One second

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `re.split()` to split the parts of the text up, and a `defaultdict()` to keep each person's conversation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

text = """Joe: hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today Joe: im bored. Mike: hey joe not sure, do you have any plans? Joe: i was thinking about going to the baseball game Joe: I need to get out of the house. Mike: Sounds good I'll meet you there! Mike: Let me know what time you're leaving"""
conversation = re.split(r'\s*?\b(\w+):\s+', text)[1:]
per_person = defaultdict(list)

for name, message in zip(*[iter(conversation)] * 2):
    per_person[name].append(message)

print(per_person['Joe'])
print(per_person['Mike'])

# Join sentences together
print(' '.join(per_person['Joe']))
```

This would give you:

```
["hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today", 'im bored.', 'i was thinking about going to the baseball game', 'I need to get out of the house.']
['hey joe not sure, do you have any plans?', "Sounds good I'll meet you there!", "Let me know what time you're leaving"]

hey mike i was wondering what you're doing today im bored. i was thinking about going to the baseball game I need to get out of the house.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [is what you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdlzW.png) ?

```
Joe:.+?(?=((Joe:)|(Mike:)))
```

Comment: Code format is a newline, then four whitespaces, the [**help-page for more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).